# Solr 5: Adding a new Core fails out of the box

Tags: solr

So I'm just playing around with Solr 5, but I tried to add a new Core through the Admin UI and the command line with:

```
bin/solr create -c new_core
```

But in both situations I get the following error:

```
new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core new_core: Error loading solr config from /Users/blah/lib/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

I started my Solr server using this:

```
bin/solr start
```

I'm following the docs here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

So what's the fix?  How was this supposed to work out of the box given I assume there must be some template that the Admin UI uses when creating new cores?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is coming because there is no `new_core` configured in your setup.
Please perform the following steps:

```
mkdir /Users/blah/lib/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/core_name
echo "name=core_name" > /Users/blah/lib/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/core_name/core.properties
cp -r /Users/blah/lib/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf /Users/blah/lib/solr-5.3.0/server/solr/core_name/
```

Some important point to note:

1. `core.properties` and `conf` directory should be placed at same path.
2. `conf` directory will contain the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` files.

Comment: Thanks I essentially decided that is what I needed to do.  I was thinking Solr would just create a new core automatically when I filled out the buttons.  From reading the docs it seems to imply that, but copy basic_configs works.  I didn't have add the core.properties.  Solr did do that when I used the admin UI.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes. While adding the core from `Admin UI`, solr automatically creates the core.properties with default parameters.

Comment: On a mac the path was as below
/usr/local/opt/solr/server/solr/new_core